# Calling functions in componentDidUpdate. Error: React limits the number of nested updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I get from api response object:

```
timeLoad =  {
  date: "2019-07-07 12:38:08+00",
  pend: true
}
```

I want to set:

```
this.setState({
  time: this.props.timeLoad.second * 1000
})
```

---

When I get from api response object:

```
timeLoad =  {
        date: null,
        pend: false
    }
```

I want to call function start().

---

```
componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {
    if (previousProps.timeLoad !== this.timeLoad) {
        if(this.props.timeLoad && this.props.timeLoad.date && 
         this.props.timeLoad.second) {
            this.setState({
                time: this.props.timeLoad.second * 1000
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                time: 0
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Above code it works, but when I added:

```
if (this.props.timeLoad && !this.props.timeLoad.date && !this.props.timeLoad.pend) {
     this.start ();
}
```

I have error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can
>   happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside
>   componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of
>   nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

How can I fix it?

I tried  deep comparison with the property's value:
`(previousProps.timeLoad.second !== this.timeLoad.second)` but I have error:

> Cannot read property 'second' of null.

Not every object has the 'second' property or has 'null' property.

```
class Watch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      timerOn: false,
      timerStart: 0,
      time: 0
    }
   }

    componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {
        if (previousProps.timeLoad !== this.timeLoad) {
            if(this.props.timeLoad && this.props.timeLoad.second && 
             this.props.timeLoad.second) {
                this.setState({
                    time: this.props.timeLoad.second * 1000
                })
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    time: 0
                })
            }
        }

        if(this.props.timeLoad  && !this.props.timeLoad.date && !this.props.timeLoad.pend){
            this.start();
        }
    }


    start = () => {
        this.setState({
            timerOn: true,
            time: this.state.time,
            timerStart: Date.now() - this.state.time
        });
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({
                time: Date.now() - this.state.time
            });
        }, 10);

        const url = `https://app/api/v1/asset/{id}`

        axios({ 
            method: 'post', 
            url, 
            data: this.item, 
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }, 
            }) 
            .then(res => { 
                this.setState({
                    startItem: res.data.item,
                })
            }).catch(err => { 
                console.log(err); 
            });
     };

        render() {
            return ( 
                <button className="play" onClick={this.start}>
                    Button
                </button>
            );
        }
 }
```

Comment: instead of `previousProps.time !== this.time` try `previousProps.time !== this.props.time`

Comment: I suppose, you should check against previousState not prevoisProps because you update state of the component.

Comment: @Janiis  `if (previousState.time !== this.time)` or  `if (previousState.time !== this.props.time)`  ?

Comment: Your time is in components state, so I would go with `if (previousState.time !== this.state.time)`. It would be more of help if you could prepare codesandbox for easier bug tracking.

Comment: One more thing: why do you set the same value to the same variable in start() function in the.setState..  `time: this.state.time`, there is no need for that.

Comment: @Janiis I'm sorry. I updated my answer. It should be `(previousProps.timeLoad !== this.timeLoad)` timeLoad not time. timeLoad is from another component as props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it:

I had to put

```
if(this.props.timeLoad  && !this.props.timeLoad.date && 
    !this.props.timeLoad.pend){
       this.start();
}
```

inside  `if (previousProps.timeLoad !== this.timeLoad) {}`

```
 componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {
        if (previousProps.timeLoad !== this.timeLoad) {
            if(this.props.timeLoad && this.props.timeLoad.second && 
             this.props.timeLoad.second) {
                this.setState({
                    time: this.props.timeLoad.second * 1000
                })
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    time: 0
                })
            }

            if(this.props.timeLoad  && !this.props.timeLoad.date && 
              !this.props.timeLoad.pend){
                 this.start();
             }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a shallow comparison:

```
if (previousProps.timeLoad !== this.timeLoad)
```

Will always return `true` (different objects) and update the state every time, this is what is causing the infinite loop. Try a deep comparison with the property's value:

```
if (previousProps.timeLoad.seconds !== this.timeLoad.seconds)
```

Comment: `componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {
  if (previousProps.loadTime.second !== this.props.loadTime.second) {`                                                                              **or **                                                                    
   `componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {
  if (previousProps.loadTime.second !== this.loadTime.second) {`  ?

Comment: TypeError: When I set: `if (previousProps.timeLoad.second !== this.timeLoad.second)` Cannot read property 'second' of null. Not every object has the 'second' property or has 'null' property